# Applying Javascript to external file

Tags: javascript, html

I have a folder with many HTML documents, named *001.html* to *999.html*. In each document, there are the following lines:

```
<span class="my-name">Name X</span>
```

I want access to the content of this `<span>`, which I can get by opening the document in my browser and then entering the following in my addressbar:

```
javascript:document.getElementById('my-name').innerHTML;
```

Without altering the HTML documents, and without having to do it manually, how can I write a script which loads these HTML documents externally, applies the javascript above and returns the content of the `<span>`?

Comment: It's not possible without altering the HTML, you would need to include the script on each of these pages.

Comment: Can I not write a new HTML document with some script like: myurl='001.html'; myurl.getElementById('my-name').innerHTML; or something?

Comment: Otherwise, perhaps using PHP?

Comment: No, because only that page would have access to that function. You would either need to place the script into each individual HTML page or use PHP to create a header file that loads a single file containing the script and include it on each page, either way you would have to alter every HTML file.

Comment: If this is just for your own use, another option would be to create a macro to visit each of those pages and run the script the way you're doing it currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need some kind of HTML parser. [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) is a good option. You can read each individual file, search for the span, and print out the result. JavaScript is not enough for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Run this from an HTML file in the same folder. Code is not tested:

```
function read(i, toIncl, done, result, iframe) {
    if (i <= toIncl) {
        if (!result) {
            result = [];
        }
        if (!iframe) {
            iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
            iframe.style.display = 'none';
            document.body.appendChild(iframe);
            iframe.onload = function () {
                result.push(iframe.contentWindow.document.querySelector('.my-name').textContent);
                read(++i, toIncl, done, result, iframe);
            }
        }
        iframe.src = ('000' + i).substr(-3) + '.html';
    } else {
        iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
        done(result);
    }
}

read(0, 999, function (result) {
    console.log('Result:', result);
})
```

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate the effort.